# Python Unit Testing - Should Other ClassMethods be Mocked?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking

This is more of a process question than anything else, but I have been programming in Python for a bit now, and I am trying to understand the differences between Unit Tests, Functional Tests, and when to appropriately use mocks in order to test functions. I have the following arrangement:

```
@classmethod
def get_value(cls, key):
    if cls._definitionsDict is None:
        cls.load_definitions()

    if not key in cls._definitionsDict:
        return None
    else:
        return cls._definitionsDict[key]
```

Basically, now I want to write some tests for this function. There are three approaches that I am considering, and I am really unsure which would be the proper (read: most widely accepted) way of doing things.

1. Write a test that mocks the `load_definitions` function, ensuring that when `cls._definitionsDict` is `None`, `load_definitions` is called with no args. (I'm assuming this is a "strict unit test")
2. Write a test that does not mock the `load_definitions` function, but simply ensures that output is as expected given a certain input. (I'm assuming this is a "strict functional test")
3. Do both in order to test that code flow works properly and the function works as intended. This seems extremely redundant to me.

I would love your thoughts and opinions on this. I suppose, in a sense, this question is asking about where to draw the line with mocks. What should really be mocked? Is a unit test testing code flow, or simply the input/output of a function?

As an additional note, option number 1 seems to be something true to the idea of "unit" testing; however, any change in the source code would also require the test to be updated. Is this the goal of a unit test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are a bit confused about the various ways to classify tests. Let me try to clarify.

Unit tests are the lowest level of tests, higher levels are module, integration and system tests.

Functional tests are tests that are only looking at 'functional' aspects, not at 'non-functional' aspects of code. Functional tests can be performed at every level.

The difference between 1 and 2 in your question is that 1 is a 'white-box' test, and 2 a 'black-box' test. Black-box tests operate only at the public interface of a unit/module/system, white-box tests also look inside the code being tested.

My personal ideas about testing are as follows:

- Try to test the most code with the least amount of effort -- meaning I prefer system tests over unit tests, and black-box tests over white-box tests.
- For complex algorithms, I use white-box unit-tests to ensure the algorithm is correct in all corner cases.
- Once the project reaches a certain maturity (preferably *before* it is released to customers ;-) I let the tests be run automatically by a continuous integration framework like Jenkins.
- Look at test coverage and strive for 100%!

Comment: Thank you very much for providing this insight. From your comment and from other research I've been doing - here's what I understand: White-box tests can be written by the developer in order to test the flow of code. These can be written at the time of development. Black-box tests, however, are usually written by someone else and work as _acceptance tests_, aka functional tests.

Thus, in the code from the original question, white-box unit tests could serve as something I _could_ do in order to ensure solid code, while black-box tests are something I **should** do.

Comment: if you can sufficiently test your code with black-box tests, you can skip the white-box tests. There is no law stopping you from writing black-box tests, though I agree that in a perfect world, someone else should write them. Many testing departments are not capable of writing tests (in code): they can only perform manual tests against the User Interface. But perhaps you can pair-up with a college, and write tests for each other's code.